# IpersistFile Interface Load method in ShellExtension using C++

Tags: visual-c++, shell

I am using IpersistFile Interface Load method in ShellExtension using C++
When i double click on any Text file Load event  of IpersistFile gets fired.
Now i want to know when i double click on any Binary File (Image,videos, audios) this load event is not getting fired.

Any other interface i need to include ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of shell extension?

Presumably you are currently registering your shell extension against the .txt filetype.

If you want it to see other filetypes you have to register it against them (or one of the generic types like *).